# How to use actual Google Authentication on Python Development Web Server

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-app-engine, google-api

I am working on a Google App Engine web app based on Python webapp2 and using the Google Api client library (Python version). 
Although the app is currently running on the local server (Python Dev. Web Server) I need it to perform the actual Gmail authentication (not the fake one which is usually run on the local server when using create_login_url). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The "fake one", is used to imitate the Google login in a local environment, so there is no way to physically log in using the Users API and your Google account when running on the local dev server.

You could switch to [OAuth2 login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login), with a redirect API pointing to your local server (which you will need to whitelist in the cloud console). This will then allow you to log in with your Google Account whilst running locally, but this approach does not use the Users API.